# Angular 9 upgrade from angular 8 Unexpected value ModuleName in path imported by OtherModule in path please add @NgModule annotation

Tags: angular, angular9

I have a library test1, which has 2 modules moduletest and moduletest2, moduletest2 uses moduletest, which is migrated to ng9.
now migrating another library test2, which uses both moduletest and moduletest2 in one of the modules in test2 library, while building the library test2, getting the error

Unexpected value moduletest in path(path of module in test2 library) imported by OtherModule(module of test2) in path please add @NgModule annotation.

Same import structure works fine with angular 8.

Comment: You seems to forget to add `@NgModule` annotation

Comment: was able to solve it by exporting all components in public api which were exported as a part of module

Comment: You can self-answer to share how you fix it